# Check CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED in Android Q not works

Tags: android, bluetooth, broadcastreceiver, android-bluetooth, android-broadcast

I use a broadcast receiver to check Bluetooth connection state changed. But not work in Android 10 and Google doesn't have information about this.

In other versions works fine but in Android Q not.

My configuration in AndroidManifest file:

```
<intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.bluetooth.adapter.action.STATE_CHANGED" />
       <action android:name="android.bluetooth.adapter.action.CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED" />
</intent-filter>
```

When I turn off Bluetooth manually the logcat print:

```
D/BluetoothAdapter: onBluetoothServiceDown: android.bluetooth.IBluetooth$Stub$Proxy@f426e8c
```

And when I turn on the logcat print:

```
D/BluetoothAdapter: onBluetoothServiceUp: android.bluetooth.IBluetooth$Stub$Proxy@f426e8c
```

Is a restriction from Android Q? Is possible to handler `onBluetoothServiceUp` or `onBluetoothServiceDown`? I need help please

Thanks

Comment: I've answered here in another question which works for me : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29609557/how-to-detect-that-the-disconnecting-bluetooth-audio-device-is-the-current-devic/66142667#66142667